# Does BADA 2.0 support horizontal list or a page control like iphone?

Tags: bada

1. I want to make a part of a screen horizontally scrollable like the page control option provided in iPhone(see first image), Does bada 2.0 supports page control or horizontal scroll?
2. if bada don't support page controls can we use ListContextItem of a listview like a page control and how many context item can we add to this list?
3. Can we add multiple lists to a form like one horizontal list and one vertical list as shown in second image?

[image: iPhone page control]

[image: Bada 2.0 page control]

Answer (score 2):

I got this response on bada developer forum:

**Refer to bada IDE(of 2.0.2 sdk)->help->Help contents->bada C++ App Programming > API Reference > Namespace List > Osp::Ui>Osp::Ui::Animations::FrameAnimator Class Reference Namespace Reference**

Answer (score 0):

In answer, basically bada doesn't support horizontal lists or scrolling unless you code it yourself. I suppose you could trick the orientation into emulating horizontal scrolling, but fading in pages from left to right and vice versa shouldn't be too tricky to animate.

The one Control I have found that provides horizontal scrolling is the new [Gallery](http://developer.bada.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppapireference.help/classOsp_1_1Ui_1_1Controls_1_1Gallery.html) and again [here](http://horrorcoding.altervista.org/bada-2-0-how-to-create-an-image-gallery-with-the-gallery-control/).